# Theano: Restoring broadcastable settings after dense -> sparse -> dense transformation

Tags: sparse-matrix, theano, array-broadcasting

Background: I'm working on a project that historically has relied on sparse matrices for a lot of the math, and developing a plugin to outsource some of the heavy lifting to theano. Since theano's sparse support is limited, we're building a dense version first -- but hopefully that explains why we're interested in the approach below.

The task: apply some operator to only the nonzero values of a matrix.

The following subroutine works most of the time:

```
import theano.sparse.basic as TSB  
def _applyOpToNonzerosOfDense(self,op,expr):                   
    sparseExpr = TSB.clean(TSB.csr_from_dense(expr))
    newData = op(TSB.csm_data(sparseExpr)).flatten()
    newSparse = TS.CSR(newData, \
                       TSB.csm_indices(sparseExpr), \
                       TSB.csm_indptr(sparseExpr), \
                       TSB.csm_shape(sparseExpr))
    ret = TSB.dense_from_sparse(newSparse)
    return ret
```

The problem comes when `expr` is not a canonical matrix tensor, but a row tensor (so, `expr` is 1xN and `expr.broadcastable` is `(True, False)`). When that happens, we need to be able to retain or restore the broadcast status in the returned tensor.

Some things I've tried that don't work:

- `dense_from_sparse` doesn't support broadcastable settings
- Theano 0.9 doesn't support assignment to `ret.broadcastable`
- `ret.dimshuffle( ('x',1) )` fails with "You cannot drop a non-broadcastable dimension."

`ret` has (ought to have) exactly the same shape as `expr`, so I wasn't expecting this to be hard. How do I get my broadcast settings back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL, it's in the API: [`T.addbroadcast(x,*axes)`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.addbroadcast)